# Compiling 1 file with Javac / Ant also compiles imported file/class in specified file

Tags: java, junit, ant, javac

The task at hand is to separately compile Java classes and their associated JUnit 'Test' classes using Ant-script. 
The regular classes are stored in 'src', while the test classes are stored in 'test/src'. Regular classes should be compiled to 'bin' and test classes to 'test/bin'. Both are in the same package.

My Ant script looks as follows:

```
<javac
     includeantruntime="false"
     classpathref="master-classpath"
     destdir="${test.class.build.dir}" 
                                        >
     <src path="${src.dir}"/>
     <src path="${test.class.dir}"/>
     <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
</javac>
```

And running the script shows me only one file will be compiled:

```
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\AK_Flex\Desktop\HW01\test\bin
```

However, the test class as well as the regular class it imports (already compiled in 'bin') are being compiled and outputted to the 'test/bin' folder.
The regular classes do not import the test classes, so 'bin' looks as desired. (code not depicted)
Is there any way to circumvent this behavior of the compiler?

Comment: Yes, `javac` does that, it compiles classes the named class(es) depend on, if necessary.

Comment: What does "if necessary" mean in this context? Is there a way to show the compiler the already compiled file, so it doesn't compile it again?

Comment: maybe `-implicit:none` can help, based on [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/javac.html) of `javac`: "If you want to be able to refer to types in additional source files but do not want them to be compiled, use the -implicit option.". Regarding your comment: `-classpath`?

Comment: @Jordan181 Yes, put the already compiled file on the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want compiled classes in two different folders, you need two compilation steps.

```xml
<javac includeantruntime="false"
       srcdir="src"
       destdir="bin"
       classpathref="master-classpath">
</javac>
<javac includeantruntime="false"
       srcdir="test/src"
       destdir="test/bin">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <path refid="master-classpath"/>
    </classpath>
</javac>
```

Comment: Thank you it works as intended now, I did 2 compilation steps but was missing the build directory path for the already built file in the second step.